# I downloaded a file from TOR and it dissapeared

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I downloaded a file from TOR and it dissapeared. Should I be worried? it also dissapeared from the download history too.

Comment: Try to do a search for the file.
Tor downloads to:
tor-browser_en-US---Browser----Downloads

Answer (score 1):

### Would this be TOR on a Tails installation?

In the case of Tails, the download would by default go to your /home/amnesia/Tor\ Browser/ directory. On Tails this location is not permanent.  Upon reboot it will vanish, as will your download history.  This behavior is normal/working-as-designed.

If this is the case, you'll need to:

- Configure permanent storage
- Re-download your file
- Move downloaded file from /home/amnesia/Tor\ Browser -> /home/amnesia/Persistent/Tor\ Browser/

### To Configure Permanent Storage

- Applications -> Tails -> Configure Persistent Volume
- At a minimum turn on Personal Data
- Click Save
- Reboot

Storage configuration changes only become active after reboot so you'll want to wait on downloading your file until after you've configured the storage.  Otherwise, you'll have nowhere to place the file for permanent storage.